# Is there any wait() function for AngularJS Jasmine test?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I created a popup, it will open on first click and will close on second click. However, I faced problem when do testing. The second click doesn't close the popup. And I found out that the problem is because during the first click the popup haven't appeared in the screen yet, that's why the second click doesn't close the popup. So, I decide to put a delay between the clicks. Any idea on how to implement the delay?

```
describe('Popup', function(){
            it("Should close on second click", function(){
                compileDirective(400,'click','true');  
                element.triggerHandler('click');
                waitttttttt(1000); // Wait function here before proceed to next line
                element.triggerHandler('click');
                scope.$digest();
                timeout.flush();
                expect($('.sidepopright').length).toBe(0);
                element.remove();
                $(".sidepopright").remove();
            });
      });
```

Answer (score 2):

what you need is `browser.waitForAngular();`

```
describe('Popup', function(){
            it("Should close on second click", function(){
                compileDirective(400,'click','true');  
                element.triggerHandler('click');
                browser.waitForAngular(); // Wait function here before proceed to next line
                element.triggerHandler('click');
                scope.$digest();
                timeout.flush();
                expect($('.sidepopright').length).toBe(0);
                element.remove();
                $(".sidepopright").remove();
            });
      });
```

browser.waitForAngular(); will wait till it gets the full response to the front

Comment: Hi, @malik_curtin, I tried your code, but I got this error "ReferenceError:browser is not defined", how to define it?

Comment: @user2991183 are you using protractor with jasmine here ?

Comment: if you are using karma here try adding 'ng-scenario' to frameworks in karma-config.js should looks like this frameworks:['ng-scenario','jasmine'],

Comment: I used karma... I tried add 'ng-scenario' as what you mentioned, but still the same problem...

Comment: okay here is what you need to do . install [karma-ng-scenario](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-scenario). And then in your karma.conf.js file just add **frameworks:['ng-scenario'],**. similer issue has been posted [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/issues/10) and [here](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/661)

Comment: Done install karma-ng-scenario and added in frameworks;['ng-scenario','jasmine'], but this time, the problem is "window.angular.$$csp is not a function"...

Comment: do u have any other method beside of using browser.waitForAngular(); ?

Comment: @user2991183 , It seems that you are using karma/jasmine here for a different purpose . If you want to test the user interface interactions (E2E testing) what you need to use is protractor/jasmine combination.