# How to create a wait function in AngularJS Karma - Jasmine Testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

Instead of using `browser.waitForAngular()`, is there any other ways to make a delay or wait for the previous function to finish execute before proceed to next line?
(because it create a lot of problems, example: "ReferenceError:browser is not defined", "window.angular.$$csp is not a function" of angular.js)

```
describe('Popup', function(){
            it("Should close on second click", function(){
                compileDirective(400,'click','true');  
                element.triggerHandler('click');
                waitttttttt(1000); // Wait function here before proceed to next line
                element.triggerHandler('click');
                scope.$digest();
                timeout.flush();
                expect($('.sidepopright').length).toBe(0);
                element.remove();
                $(".sidepopright").remove();
            });
      });
```

This is my previous question:: [Is there any wait() function for AngularJS Jasmine test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636916/is-there-any-wait-function-for-angularjs-jasmine-test/30637666?noredirect=1#comment49342979_30637666), But no solution. Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Unit testing with Jasmine and Karma is more suited to testing the logic of your code. An example is testing that your services make the right $http calls to your API.

Things popups hiding or showing are user interaction. To test user interaction, you should be using [protractor](https://angular.github.io/protractor).